# Is there any some way to automatically synchronize firefox and chrome browsing history?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, history, browsing

The title states the problem quite well:

Is there any some way to automatically synchronize firefox's with chrome's browsing history (and viceversa) ?

Something like XMarks, but working with the history, not only bookmarks.

Is it programatically impossible to achieve ? Why hasn't it been done ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/638252/how-to-automatically-sync-chrome-and-firefox-history-bookmarks-in-windows-seaml/1530102#1530102 same topic.. my comment to be found there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmarks ! http://www.xmarks.com/

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Xmarks does not sync history on Chrome.