# How to automatically sync chrome and firefox history, bookmarks in windows seamlessly?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, firefox, google-chrome

> Don't mark as duplicate before reading, as i read the posts and didn't
>   found the solution.

I need to know i there anyway by which i can synchronize the browsing history and bookmarks between chrome and firefox(don't want to import every time from the other browser).

Because i love to use both the browsers, but due to my browsing history and bookmarks, i have to choose which one to use at what time. I want to know is there any seamless way by which this can be done(in the background).

Previously i tried using ***xmarks***, but it doesn't work quite well(seamlessly).

Comment: I deleted my commentary about Xmarks since it was discontinued 3 years ago.

Comment: Now I only seldomly use Chrome, so no need to sync history. I switched to Firefox a while back and haven't looked back ever since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few alternatives to Xmarks, i prefer Delecious for synching bookmakrs between different browsers and machines,

[here is a link](http://www.programmerfish.com/top-3-ways-for-syncing-bookmarks-between-different-browsersexcluding-x-marks/) which gives top three alternatives to Xmarks-